# Slow loading images from sdcard to gridview

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I've been trying to create multiple image chooser, everything works fine, but the grid scroll is very lazy and slow, I've been tried to use different libraries for image loading in `getView() (Picasso,aquery..)`
but its no difference ,even with `asynctask`, that's my code:
Main:

```
public class Media extends ActionBarActivity {
    private AQuery aq;

    GridView myGridView;
    MyAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;    
    boolean isOddClicked = true;
    static String img=null;
    final Uri srcUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String srcData  = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
    final String srcImgId = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;    
    final Uri thumbUri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String thumb_DATA = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA;
    final String thumb_IMAGE_ID = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID;
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(5);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.media);


        //Always show the menu
        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if(menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            } 
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
        myGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);        
        // 
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
          this,srcUri,null,null,null,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN+ " DESC");
        //
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        //
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};
        String[] from = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new MyAdapter(
          this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            cursor,from,to,CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        //
        myGridView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);
        myGridView.setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
    }    

    OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
            Cursor cursor = mySimpleCursorAdapter.getCursor();
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            int int_ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        }
    };

    private Bitmap getThumbnail(int id){
        String[] thumbColumns = {srcData, srcImgId};
        CursorLoader thumbCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
      this,srcUri,thumbColumns,srcImgId + "=" + id,null,null);        
    Cursor thumbCursor = thumbCursorLoader.loadInBackground();
    Bitmap thumbBitmap = null;
    if(thumbCursor.moveToFirst()){
            int thCulumnIndex = thumbCursor.getColumnIndex(srcData);
            String thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thCulumnIndex);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),thumbPath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
            thumbBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbPath);          
          //Create a Dialog to display the thumbnail
            AlertDialog.Builder thumbDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Media.this);
            ImageView thumbView = new ImageView(Media.this);
            thumbView.setImageBitmap(thumbBitmap);
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(Media.this);
      layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      layout.addView(thumbView);
      thumbDialog.setView(layout);
      thumbDialog.show();           
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO Thumbnail!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    return thumbBitmap;
    }
    public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    Cursor myCursor;
      Context myContext;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,int[] to, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);         
            myCursor = c;
          myContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                convertView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_row, parent, false);   
             holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.thumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
            holder.title = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);  
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
            myCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            final int myID = myCursor.getInt(myCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
            final String[] thumbColumns = {srcData ,srcImgId};
            CursorLoader thumbCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
              myContext,srcUri,thumbColumns,srcImgId + "=" + myID,null,null);
            Cursor thumbCursor = thumbCursorLoader.loadInBackground();          
        if(thumbCursor.moveToFirst()){
          final int thCulumnIndex = thumbCursor.getColumnIndex(thumb_DATA);
              final String thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thCulumnIndex);
                Bitmap o = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), myID, Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                //holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(o);
            //Phase II:
                String uri = null;
                Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(
          getContentResolver(), myID,
          MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,null );
                if( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
                  cursor.moveToFirst();//**EDIT**
                  uri = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA ) );
                }

                MediaAsync loadAsync = new MediaAsync(getApplicationContext(), holder.thumbnail);
                loadAsync.onPostExecute(thumbPath);
                /*
                holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View v){
            img = thumbPath;
            al.add(thumbPath); 
            if (holder.title.isChecked()) {
              holder.title.setChecked(false);
              holder.thumbnail.setBackgroundResource(0);
            }else{
              holder.title.setChecked(true);
              holder.thumbnail.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.media_row_border);
            }
          }
       });
       */
            }           
            return convertView ;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.media, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.done) {
            Intent main = new Intent(this, Main.class);
            main.putStringArrayListExtra("media_lst", al);
            startActivity(main);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView thumbnail;
        CheckBox title;
    }
}
```

mediaAsynce :

```
public class MediaAsync extends AsyncTask<String,String, String>{
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Context mContext;

    public  MediaAsync(Context context,ImageView imageView) {
        mImageView = imageView;
        mContext   = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0].toString();
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(result));

        Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(uri)
        //.resize(100, mWidth)
        .into(mImageView);
        //  AQuery aq = new AQuery(mContext);
        //  aq.id(mImageView).image(result,  true, true, 0, R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }
}
```

Comment: refer to [this link](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have tried picasso library it should work

Just try once again using picassso like this Async task and all is not required

Just create a simple adapter and load images.

```
public class GridViewDynamicAdapter extends BaseDynamicGridAdapter {
ImageDetails details;
public static List<ImageDetails> list;

public GridViewDynamicAdapter(Context context, List<ImageDetails> items,
        int columnCount) {
    super(context, items, columnCount);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheeseViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_grid, null);
        holder = new CheeseViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (CheeseViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (position == getCount() - 1) {
        ImageApplication.fromRecorderPaths = (List<ImageDetails>) getItems();
    }
    details = (ImageDetails) getItem(position);
    // Log.d("Setting=", details.path);
    holder.build(getContext(), details.path);
    return convertView;
}

private class CheeseViewHolder {
    private ImageView image;

    private CheeseViewHolder(View view) {
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_img);
    }

    void build(final Context context, String title) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(new File(title)).centerCrop()
                .resize(150, 150).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(image);
    }
}

}
```

**OR**

[Try this example](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)